# same button, each click performs another function... HOW?

Tags: html, button

I have a website that has multiple languages, currently the language bar is displayed along the top of the site with a button for each language. What I would prefer is one button, click it once, the button image changes to a union jack flag, and english is called, press it again, and the button image changes to french, and the french language is called, etc etc..

Is this one button, multiple calls possible? can anyone give me a good place to start looking in to this?

Comment: You could include a condition that checks the current source of the button image and changes it to the opposite one accordingly. Sorry this is so descriptive, but if you ask a handwavy question you get a handwavy answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.
Your `html` would look something like this:

```
<button id='changeLang' onclick='changeLang()'></button>
```

(Remember to set this to your default to begin with)

and your javascript:

```
    var counter = 0;
    function changeLang(){
       var buttonDetails = document.getElementById('changeLang');
       buttonDetails.innerHTML = "";
       switch(counter){

          case 0:
             buttonDetails.innerHTML = "<img src='unionJack.png' />English";
             counter +=1;
             break;
          case 1:
             buttonDetails.innerHTML = "<img src='frenchFlag.png' />French";
             counter +=1;
             break;
          case 2:
             //continue like above
          default:
             counter = 0;
             changeLang();
   }
}
```

If you ever need another language, just add it to the switch.

Alternatively, change the case code to:

```
case 0:
   buttonDetails.src = "unionJack.png";
   counter +=1;
   break;
```

And remove the line that says `buttonDetails.innerHTML = "";` if all you want is an image.

To call a function to change the language you would simply add a function call to one of your switch cases like so:

```
case 0:
   buttonDetails.innerHTML = "<img src='unionJack.png' />English";
   counter +=1;
   foo(bar);     //just add your function call
   break;
```

Comment: Alternatively, if it's just the image you wish to change, try: `document.getElementById("img").src="image.png";` I'll edit the answer to include that...

Comment: The question is a little unclear as to if you want to _just_ change the image or also call a function that changes the page's language, which is easily done by adding that function call to the relevant switch case. If that is indeed the real question, let me know and I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: that is indeed what I am trying to do (call a function). Thanks!

Comment: Great @user1833002, I've updated the answer to reflect that. Don't forget to mark it as answered so that others with the same problem can find it easier! :)